# C# project is getting build but it doesn't run

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop

I am new to C# and its my first project and want to understand complete flow of code. I am using sharp develop IDE 4.4 to run project.

When I run it open a local host and message appears-
Make sure you’ve got the right web address: http://localhost:52440

Output when I build a project-

```
Build started.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1635,5) : Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1635,5) : Warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\\mscorlib.dll", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1635,5) : Warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Data", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1635,5) : Warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.EnterpriseServices", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1635,5) : Warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Web", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
Build finished successfully. (00:00:00.5339523)
```

Comment: Change your output platform to X86

Comment: I received an error now when I build a project-The OutputPath property is not set for project 'ASPV.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Release'  Platform='X86'.  This error may also appear if some other project is trying to follow a project-to-project reference to this project, this project has been unloaded or is not included in the solution, and the referencing project does not build using the same or an equivalent Configuration or Platform.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which IDE you're using but are you trying to do an asp\mvc site project or is it desktop project in which u search to run an executable?.

if you're trying to do a desktop project and run it then you probably chose the wrong kind of project. if u do want to run a website then you first should look into the project routes and web config and see that all is in order.

Comment: Its a web project and I just opened a solution in "Sharpdevelop" IDE, and it works perfectly fine in visual studio but due to license concern I tried to configure same project in Sharp Develop IDE. It should open and run as it does in Visual studio but it doesn't run as a localhost and at a build it throws  warning mentioned in my question.

Comment: you can also try to use the community version of visual studio it is free for use